# Confusion on number of component of Cauchy stress tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, material-science

The Cauchy stress tensor is often presented as a tensor having $(2,0)$ tensor having nine components in any given basis. However, I think it should actually be $6 \times 3 =18$ because a cube has six faces and each face there are three direction forces can act. So, how where did half the theoretical components from the calculation I described go?

Answer (score 1):

For an infinitesimal  cube, when the forces are ${\bf F}_a$ for the $a=x,y,x$  faces, the forces on the $-x,-y,-z$ opposite faces are simply $-{\bf F}_a$.  You only need three faces to specify the  stress therefore.

Comment: Why it negative? It is not obvious to me.

Comment: This is explained in any intro text. Basically if the cube has side  length $l$ then its mass is proprtional to $l^3$. The force on  each face is $\propto l^2$ so if the opposite forces did not add to zero the cube would accelerate $\propto 1/l\to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike! I'll see other answer if they can offer another prespective and accept the best

Comment: It might be useful to note that the Cauchy stress tensor includes all loading that does not accelerate the center of mass. This constrains opposite forces to be equal so that static equilibrium is maintained. Consequently, the forces on all six sides are not independent.

Comment: Seems if the forces on opposite faces are not equal, there still exists possibility to make the infinitesimal cube static, which means they don't have to be negative to each other.